# Number of factors of a polynomial with integer coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the Ring R of polynomials in n variables with integer coefficients. Prove that the polynomial $f(x_1,x_2,....x_n)$=$x_1x_2.....x_n$ has $2^{n+1} -2$ non constant polynomials in R dividing it.

I get $2^n-1$. Why is the answer double my answer? Is it because of $\pm$? Or is there any other catch?

Comment: Adding your answer would greatly help others understand where you're coming from. After pretending to read your mind, I do believe it's because of the $ \pm$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you for the fine sentiments expressed.